# Gets multiple events call back from angular end socket.io

Tags: angularjs, socket.io

(X) First Scenario
We have a web application and we are using socket.io as middleware. There is an angular end and there are API from .net. and it is a chat application, when a user sends a message it calls for the socket server and from socket server, we call to the API and we send the message to the particular socket. but when we send the message to the client the client event gets called multiple times(not every time but sometimes) from the angular end but the message, we have only sent once from the server(we set a logger to confirm this from server end). We have Azure Linux server. We are pooling socket ids from user ids as rooms. Though we removed rooms and added a manual array to pool sockets ids from user ids issue still exists. Working fine on android and ios devices.

****Second scenario
when we disconnect internet connection and reconnect the connection gets to connect to the server and we send a message after that it does send the message to other ends, but if we are sending messages from other end, messages are not coming to this end, from loggers in a server it shows that messages are sent. to the particular socket ids.

Setup

socket.io version: V2.0.3
node 6.11.4